# Calculating a value based on another columns value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV that has two columns: ['item', 'price]. I want to calculate the total price of each item separately. For example, let's say that the 'item' column has 4 rows with the value 'brown shoes'. I want to find the sum of 'price' when df['item'] is equal to 'brown shoes'.

I have tried this:

```
for i in df['item']:
        if i == 'brown shoes':
           df = df.loc['price'].sum()
```

Not sure why this isn't working. The error i'm getting is:

**"Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).**

Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Use `df.loc[df['item'] == "brown shoews", 'price'].sum()`

Comment: I think you want `df.groupby('item')['price'].sum()`

Comment: @Erfan can you vote to close when you get a mo?

Comment: Error aside, that’s an unidiomatic way of doing things. I urge you to read the pandas docs.